# How to factorise it?

Tags: factoring

Can you explain to me how to factorise it? and I should remove a common factor before factorising the trinomials.
This question...
$$
4x^2 + 12xy +9y^2
$$

Comment: Perhaps you could compare that with
$$
(a+b)^2 = a^2 +2ab + b^2
$$
Can you find $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: Look at $(2X+3Y)^2$

Comment: Can you factorise $4x^2+12x+9$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$4x^2+12xy+9y^2$$
$$=4x^2+6xy+6xy+9y^2$$
$$=(4x^2+6xy)+(6xy+9y^2)$$

What common factor can you take out from each bracket?

Comment: it will be 2x(2x + 3y) + 3y(2x + 3y) then (2x + 3y) (2x + 3y)   Thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^2 + 12xy + 9y^2$$
$$= (2x)^2 + 2(2x)(3y) + (3y^2)$$
Write formula $$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$Then evaluate $a = 2x$ and $b = 3y$. Are you done with it?

Comment: This will be ..(2x + 3y) (2x + 3y) .Thanks.

Comment: @user822674 You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

the discriminant of $a x^2 +bxy + c y^2 $ is
$$  b^2 - 4ac  $$
same as in the Quadratic formula. With integer abc and any common integer factor pulled out, especially any $-1,$ so that $a \geq 0 \; \; : \; \;$ if the discriminant is a positive square, the thing factors nicely. If, in addition, the discriminant is exactly $0,$  the thing itself is a square. Since 4 and 9 are squares, the choices are
$$ (2x-3y)^2 $$
$$ (2x+3y)^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Denote this function as $f(x,y)=4x^2+12xy+9y^2$ and let it equal $0$. You can treat either $x$ or $y$ as constant, and reduce this as a function of either $x$ or $y$. For example, I treat it as a function of $x$ and consider the discriminant of the function:
$$\Delta=144y^2-4\times 4\times 9y^2=0$$
which implies this function has only one root of order $2$, which is $$x=-\frac{3}{2}y$$
Hence $$f(x,y)=\left(2x+3y\right)^2$$